# PowerShell Attempted to Read or Write Protected Memory

Tags: c, powershell, memory, memory-management

I'm not at all a PowerShell aficionado, but I know my way around C. I'm getting an error after allocating memory with VritualAlloc() and using memset() to write to it.

Also, I am running this from SysWOW64 for x86 compatibility. If the architecture is x64, it will restart the PS1 and execute it from SysWOW64

Relevant Code:

```
$code = @"
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr VirtualAlloc(IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr CreateThread(IntPtr lpThreadAttributes, uint dwStackSize, IntPtr lpStartAddress, IntPtr lpParameter, uint dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpThreadId);
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr memset(IntPtr dest, uint src, uint count);
"@
$win = Add-Type -memberDefinition $code -Name "Win32" -namespace Win32Functions -passthru
$size = 100;

$vptr=$win::VirtualAlloc(0,0x1000,$size,0x40)
#0x1000 = MEM_COMMIT, 0x40 = PAGE_EXECUE_READWRITE

$win::memset([IntPtr]$vptr, 0x00, 1)
```

Error I am receiving:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected\
memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Relevant "bcdedit" information:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
integrityservices       Enable
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {dda7e6ba-e18d-11e3-b50a-ecf4bb7add72}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 8.1
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {dda7e6c4-e18d-11e3-b50a-ecf4bb7add72}
integrityservices       Enable
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \windows
resumeobject            {dda7e6ba-e18d-11e3-b50a-ecf4bb7add72}
nx                      AlwaysOn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
vga                     No
quietboot               Yes
bootlog                 No
sos                     No
```

Does this have to do with DEP/NX? I'm not in a place where I can simply reboot my machine right now.

Comment: shouldn't it be `$win::VirtualAlloc(0,$size,0x1000,0x40)`?

Comment: I thought so at first, but that did not work wither. Even when I do `$win::VirtualAlloc(0,0x1000,0x1000,0x40)` for safety, I get the same error.

Comment: My thinking is that it has something to do with DEP, but I have no way of knowing.

Comment: I tested it on a Windows 10 machine with the NX set to OptIn. Same result

Comment: It seems as if I can execute this using the `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::Copy()` function and using `VirtualAlloc([IntPtr]0,$size, 0x3000, 0x40)`. I will update this post later on when I get a working proof of concept.

Comment: I have working code that uses `[runtime.interopservices.marshal]::copy` and `[runtime.interopservices.marshal]::AllocCoTaskMem`. So if you don't need `VirtualAlloc`, then I'd suggest these instead - they don't require any C# code.